# How to replace GUID in records and then return only unique ones in Excel "Unique" formula?

Tags: excel, replace, unique, formula, guid

**Description:**

I have a list of records (API requests) with different GUIDs in A:A column on each Excel tab.
GUID format ********-****-****-************.
Every such record contains slash and text before and after GUID.
There are also records without GUIDs.
How to return only unique records while ignoring different GUID values?

I can retrieve all unique records, but now need to replace GUIDs with i.e. "{id}" word, and shorten the list even more skipping GUID values uniqueness.

**Excel formula (need to fix to replace GUIDs as well, and return only unique):**

```
=iferror(unique({Sheet1!A:A; Sheet2!A:A}), "")
```

**Input:**

```
AAA/d20b334e-76c7-e811-a982-f2cb536a8f94/BBB
AAA/d20b334e-76c7-e811-a982-f2cb536a8f94/BBB
AAA/c63cb3bb-1f49-e811-a981-ee3456e98dd2/BBB
AAA/c63cb3bb-1f49-e811-a981-ee3456e98dd2
CCC/d20b334e-76c7-e811-a982-f2cb536a8f94
GGG/c63cb3bb-1f49-e811-a981-ee3456e98dd2/HHH
GGG/d20b334e-76c7-e811-a982-f2cb536a8f94/HHH
record-without-id-1
record-without-id-1
record-without-id-2
```

**Actual result:**

```
AAA/d20b334e-76c7-e811-a982-f2cb536a8f94/BBB
AAA/c63cb3bb-1f49-e811-a981-ee3456e98dd2/BBB
AAA/c63cb3bb-1f49-e811-a981-ee3456e98dd2
CCC/d20b334e-76c7-e811-a982-f2cb536a8f94
GGG/c63cb3bb-1f49-e811-a981-ee3456e98dd2/HHH
GGG/d20b334e-76c7-e811-a982-f2cb536a8f94/HHH
record-without-id-1
record-without-id-2
```

**Expected result:**

```
AAA/{id}/BBB
AAA/{id}
CCC/{id}
GGG/{id}/HHH
record-without-id-1
record-without-id-2
```

Comment: Use left() and right() to get the 3 characters from each end of the string , consider if() to make sure of the length of the string and presence of AAA etc Create that list, then use "remove duplicates".

Comment: That's good, best bit is how much you have learnt from it ! have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

That was a long journey but I solved it today! :)
Had to create another 'transfer' column to do this action before pushing final unique values to the summary sheet via mentioned originally function.
So the main idea here is to calculate position of the first dash and the GUID length in the string as we know exact GUID format.
Note this solution works only for the case when dashes exist only within GUID so the rest of the record should be without dashes.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1, FIND("-",A1)-8, 36),"{id}")
```

where
**FIND("-",A1)-8** is the start of GUID (8 symbols before the first dash)
**36** is the length of GUID

Answer (score 0):

```
=regexreplace(A1,"[0-9a-f]{8}?[-]?(?:[0-9a-f]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9a-f]{12}?","{id}")
```

Comment: Your answer would be so much better if you added done explanation to it. That way, others would be able to follow your explanation and apply it to their own problems (and you'd get upvotes). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22489899).